# one-page website with multiple sections hidden until its link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I must not know how to phrase this question properly because a few hours later, I still have yet to find the coding that will implement what I want. . .

I do NOT want a continuously-scrolling one-page website of multiple 'sections'. I want to create a single-page website with four content sections, and each section will remain hidden until the link designated for it is clicked & reveals the content. I am looking for the simple framework---html, css, JavaScript/Jquery/whatever (I'm not sure which would be best).

A website that replicates what I want: http://giorgibou.com/

Comment: http://www.jqueryrain.com/?m6MaiPX9

Answer (score 1):

Though this question is a bit vague, I believe what you need to research is the CSS display value. Using jQuery's toggle method it is rather simple to hide/show sections by clicking links or buttons:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- These buttons hide or show both sections plus all buttons, 
     depending on their current display value (none or block) -->
<button class="tog" style="display: none" onclick="$('.tog').toggle()">
   Section 1
</button>
<button class="tog" onclick="$('.tog').toggle()">
   Section 2
</button>
<div class="tog" style="background-color: green; color: white">
   This is Section 1.
</div>
<div class="tog" style="background-color: blue; color: white; display: none">
   This is Section 2.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I am about to say is more of suggestions/tips than actual solution.

I visited the link http://giorgibou.com/ and explored for a bit.

I'v realized that every time when you click a navigation, the URL of website doesn't change. I don't exactly know what tools you're using to make a website but if you're using javascript, html, css and jquery you can simply look into frameworks like Node JS. You can easily manipulate and control routes.

For example: If "Home" link is clicked, then render "some_page.html" without directing to new link or any.

I hope this helps you a bit. Node JS is pretty good framework to consider when building a single page website/ a dynamic website/ a static website.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide all of your page sections with CSS, except when the .active class is applied to it. You can use javascript or jquery to add and remove the .active class on corresponding link click like you are saying:

**HTML**

```
<div class="page-section page-1 active"></div>

<button class="link link-1">Page 1 link</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.page-section {
    display: none;
}

.page-section.active {
    display: block;
}
```

**JS**

```
function pageActivator(page) {
    $('.page-section').removeClass('active');
    page.addClass('active');
}

$('.link').click(function() {
    var pageNum = parseInt($(this).attr('class').match(/\d+/g)[0]);
    pageActivator($('.page-' + pageNum));
});
```

Here is full codepen example to get started: http://codepen.io/StefanBobrowski/pen/PpvBdg

Answer (score 1):

I made a basic replica of that website you posted here, take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/5165/

here's a brief structure:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <a id="something1">Some Link</a>
    <a id="something2">Another Link</a>
</div>
<div class="main_window">
    <section class="slider">

    </section>
</div>
```

With some CSS

```
.sidebar, .main_window {
    height: 100vh;
    float: left;
}

.main_window {
    width:  70%;
}

.slider {
    height: 400vh;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 30%;
}
```

You can then do some onclick() events with jQuery, ex

```
$('#something1').click(function() {
    // change margin-top of .slider
});
```

then change the margin-top property of .slider to **negative** multiples of your window height (to make it scroll up) and have it animate

Basically there's a sidebar on the left and a content area. Both are floated left so they're in line with each other, and their heights are set to the full height of the window. In the div to the right there's another section that's 4 times the height of the window. It holds your content. When you click on the links, the jQuery will change the margin-top of that slider window, which moves it up and down. If you take the overflow:hidden off of the main_window, you'll get a better idea of what's happening. For more content, just adjust the height of the main_window section and modify the JavaScript accordingly. There's a more elegant way to do the JavaScript without that switch case, but I was lazy.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very broad question. You can look at how the effect you want to use is implemented on that site by right-clicking and selecting 'View Source.' There are many ways to accomplish this with or without external libraries depending on exactly what you want.

A less flashy solution is to have each section have style {display: none} by default then have this changed on button click. If you did this you'd have to also reset the other sections when the button was clicked.